# Spring 4/5 global CORS configuration doesn't work giving `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource`

Tags: spring, spring-security, cors

I am trying to login through `http://localhost:3000` using HTTP `POST.

I am getting the following:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/api/auth/login. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.

I have configured my Spring 5.0.0.M4 and Spring-Security 4.2.1.RELEASE application like that:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootApp extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    private boolean workOffline = true;
    private boolean setupSchema = false;
    private IGraphService graphService;
    private DbC conf;

    @Autowired
    public SpringBootApp(IGraphService graphService, DbC conf)
    {
        this.graphService = graphService;
        this.conf = conf;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootApp.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public Filter caseInsensitiveRequestFilter() {
        return new CaseInsensitiveRequestFilter();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
                .allowedMethods("GET", "PUT", "POST", "DELETE","OPTIONS");
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean corsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.addAllowedOrigin("http://localhost:3000");
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("*");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new CorsFilter(source));
        bean.setOrder(0);
        return bean;
    }
}
```

I don't understand why global CORS configuration doesn't work even if it seems to be configured correctly.

I have attached the console and network tabs:

[image: console tab]
[image: network tab]

Comment: I have the same problem with Spring 4.. I had to upgrade to 5 since they decided to deprecate Guava.. and I had a conflict with it and Datastax packages needing an old version

Comment: token based in the backend JWT (https://github.com/svlada/springboot-security-jwt)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With help from dur . I spotted that http://github.com/svlada/springboot-security-jwt had added a WebSecurityConfig that was overriding my spring boot application configuration.

In the configure section of `WebSecurityConfig` I added cors() before anything else as following:

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors()
        .and()
        .csrf().disable() // We don't need CSRF for JWT based authentication
        .exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(this.authenticationEntryPoint)

        .and()
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)

        .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(FORM_BASED_LOGIN_ENTRY_POINT).permitAll() // Login end-point
                .antMatchers(TOKEN_REFRESH_ENTRY_POINT).permitAll() // Token refresh end-point
                .antMatchers("/console").permitAll() // H2 Console Dash-board - only for testing
        .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(TOKEN_BASED_AUTH_ENTRY_POINT).authenticated() // Protected API End-points
        .and()
            .addFilterBefore(buildAjaxLoginProcessingFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .addFilterBefore(buildJwtTokenAuthenticationProcessingFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
```

Then I was getting an error for the corsFilter. The Bean needs to be of type `CorsFilter` but for me it was  `FilterRegistrationBean`.

So I converted the Bean in my `@SpringBootApplication` class from

```
    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean corsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.addAllowedOrigin("http://localhost:3000");
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("*");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new CorsFilter(source));
        bean.setOrder(0);
        return bean;
    }
```

to:

```
    @Bean
    public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.addAllowedOrigin("http://localhost:3000");
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("*");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        return new CorsFilter(source);
    }
```

I also removed

```
  @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
                .allowedMethods("GET", "PUT", "POST", "DELETE","OPTIONS");
    }
```

I might have to move those configurations to a single place - favorably removing WebSecurityConfig altogether

Comment: Using the mentioned CorsFilter bean is what worked for me. This was after unsucessfully trying the configuration mentioned in the Spring Security 5 Reference Guide: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/cors.html