# Adding any options or headers on the Angular 2 http.post sends OPTIONS

Tags: java, angular, authentication, spring-boot, jwt

I am trying to send token information back to the server over `http.post()`. If I remove the options from it it sends a POST but if I add them back on it sends OPTIONS which is rejected from the server code. I tried removing the "withCredentials" as well.

```
export class EntityService {

    public entity: EntityModel;
    private options: RequestOptions;

    constructor( @Inject(Http) private http: Http, @Inject(AuthenticationService) authService) {
        let headers = new Headers({ 'X-Authorization': 'Bearer ' + authService.token});
        this.options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, withCredentials: true });
    }

    public store(entity: EntityModel): Observable<string> {

        var request;
        if (!entity.uuid) {
            request = this.http.post("http://localhost:8080/api/entity", JSON.stringify(entity), this.options);
        }
        else {
            request = this.http.put("http://localhost:8080/api/entity", JSON.stringify(fact), this.options);
        }
        return request.map((res: Response) => res.text());
    }
}
```

My authentication service looks like this:

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'

//http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/08/16/angular-2-jwt-authentication-example-tutorial
@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService {
    public token: string;

    constructor(@Inject(Http) private http: Http) {
        // set token if saved in local storage
        var currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
        this.token = currentUser && currentUser.token;
    }

    login(username: string, password: string): Observable<boolean> {;
        console.log("login...");
        return this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/api/auth/login', JSON.stringify({ username: username, password: password }))
            .map((response: Response) => {
                // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
                let token = response.json() && response.json().token;
                if (token) {
                    // set token property
                    this.token = token;

                    // store username and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
                    localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify({ username: username, token: token }));

                    // return true to indicate successful login
                    return true;
                } else {
                    // return false to indicate failed login
                    return false;
                }
            });
    }

    logout(): void {
        // clear token remove user from local storage to log user out
        this.token = null;
        localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
    }
}
```

Here is my Spring configuration:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootApp extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    private boolean workOffline = true;
    private boolean setupSchema = false;
    private IGraphService graphService;
    private DbC conf;

    @Autowired
    public SpringBootApp(IGraphService graphService, DbC conf)
    {
        this.graphService = graphService;
        this.conf = conf;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootApp.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public Filter caseInsensitiveRequestFilter() {
        return new CaseInsensitiveRequestFilter();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
                .allowedMethods("GET", "PUT", "POST", "DELETE","OPTIONS");
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean corsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.addAllowedOrigin("http://localhost:3000");
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("*");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new CorsFilter(source));
        bean.setOrder(0);
        return bean;
    }
}
```

I really don't know what to do since I am following what is being said in [Angular2 OPTIONS method sent when asking for http.GET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36353532/986160) and this is not a preflight request. I had this issue earlier with the wrong content-type.

Comment: Commenting on downvotes is not required. Also downvote does not necessarily mean duplicate - some duplicates are actually useful, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual fix was due to two reasons:
 improper CORS implementation - for more please have a look here: [Spring 4/5 global CORS configuration doesn't work giving `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42052373/986160)

Then when I was POSTing after the login I was getting error `415 Unsupported Media Type`. After following the instructions here: [POST JSON fails with 415 Unsupported media type, Spring 3 mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11492325/986160)

I added `Content-Type` and `Accept` header on my request and it fixed the problem. It seems that `Content-Type` is what was actually needed.

```
export class EntityService {

    public entity: EntityModel;
    private options: RequestOptions;

    constructor( @Inject(Http) private http: Http, @Inject(AuthenticationService) authService) {
        let headers = new Headers({ 
           'X-Authorization': 'Bearer ' + authService.token,
           'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        });
        this.options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, withCredentials: true });
    }

    public store(entity: EntityModel): Observable<string> {

        var request;
        if (!entity.uuid) {
            request = this.http.post("http://localhost:8080/api/entity", JSON.stringify(entity), this.options);
        }
        else {
            request = this.http.put("http://localhost:8080/api/entity", JSON.stringify(fact), this.options);
        }
        return request.map((res: Response) => res.text());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `OPTIONS` request is made by the browser alone. Angular is not involved at all.

"and this is not a preflight request." - it definitely is.

You need to configure your server to respond properly to the `OPTIONS` request or ensure that the Angular application is loaded from the same server (also same port) as where you make the request to.

Comment: Thanks Gunter! But I haven't found a way that I can send custom header with token information without making the browser send an OPTIONS request. What I am supposed to do when someone sends OPTIONS instead of POST.. I just return nothing.. under what condition will the browser send POST after OPTIONS? I have configured my server to respond to OPTIONS and I can't have those two on the same port unfortunately since one is node.js and one is jetty

Comment: http://restlet.com/blog/2015/12/15/understanding-and-using-cors/ "POST methods, only content types with the following values are supported: text/plain, application/x-www-form-urlencoded and multipart/form-data." `withCredentials` also causes the `OPTIONS` preflight request.

Comment: The server needs to return CORS headers `AccessControlAllowXxx`

Comment: See https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework - search for "allowCredentials" - needs to be set to `true` in your case.

Comment: I am doing that: `config.setAllowCredentials(true);`

Comment: Sorry, don't know about Java, just did a Google search. In this linked doc they use `registry.allowCredentials()`. I can't tell if your approach should work as well.

Comment: What's the exact error message you get in the browser?

Comment: i don't get any error - it is just that it sends OPTIONS and it is rejected by my authentication filter `if (!HttpMethod.POST.name().equals(request.getMethod()))`

Comment: Then you should probably allow `HttpMethod.OPTIONS` here as well.

Comment: This is stopping OPTION methods: https://github.com/svlada/springboot-security-jwt/blob/7091258de487f1a5f7e82db7d67e6bcbb0a4c16a/src/main/java/com/svlada/security/auth/ajax/AjaxLoginProcessingFilter.java

I don't know what to do so that client sends a POST after initial OPTIONS

Comment: The browser sends `POST` after `OPTIONS` if it gets the right headers in the response to the `OPTIONS` request. If it doesn't, you get an error in the browser console instead telling what headers are missing.

Answer (score 0):

Using http post like this

```
import { Http, Headers, Response, Request } from '@angular/http';

let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
headers.append('X-Authorization', this.token);
headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + jwtToken);

return this.http.post(url, data, {headers})
  .map(res => { console.log(res) })
  .catch(err => { console.log(err) } );
```

Note this example returns an Observable that you can subscribe to. Also my example